# ¿Cuáles son las condiciones para que se contabilice este sitio como visitado?

Tags: soporte, perfil

Quiero conseguir la medalla

**entusiasta**

> Visitar el sitio todos los días durante 30 días consecutivos. Los días se cuentan en UTC.

Como ayer no estuve casi con el ordenador, realice una visita rápida al foro para que me actualizara el contador de visitas y no perder los días consecutivos necesarios para la medalla.

Otras veces me ha pasado y no entiendo muy bien por qué (día 28)

[image]

Pero como podéis ver, ayer realicé una visita que no parece haberse contabilizado:

[image]

Mi hora de acceso fue aproximadamente entre las 19h y 20h. Yo me encuentro en Barcelona, actualmente con zona horario UTC +2.

Esto me lleva a pensar, que no es suficiente con una visita:

- ¿Visitar una pregunta concreta?
- ¿Quizás hay que interactuar de alguna manera?
- ¿Es necesario votar?

¿Cuáles son las condiciones para que se contabilice este sitio como visitado?

Comment: Hola @Jordi. Sobre este tema, por favor te pediría que actualices la pregunta y puedas mostrar la hora en que accediste, según tu navegador. Con dicha información a la mano, podré investigar más al respecto

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no puedo sacar esa información, firefox solo guarda la fecha de la última visita en el historial y ya he vuelto a visitar la pagina... aunque te agradezco en interes. Seguro que no hay otras condiciones a parte de la hora de conexion? Por ejemplo, es obligatorio visitar una pregunta y no la home o una busqueda... Esque quizás me estoy quejando sin motivo... xD

Comment: Voy a consultar al respecto. Más bien, yo he visto el registro de tus accesos y no hay acceso tuyo registrado para el 16 de mayo.

Comment: Reemplacé "el foro" por "este sitio". Espero que no se requiera mayor explicación, pero si hace falta, sugiero que usemos el [chat].

Comment: Yo entre desde mi celular y me reinicio el contador, pareciera como si estuviera trucado..
Saludos!!!

Comment: Además de entrar ¿Hiciste algo más?

Comment: Hola @Rubén, Vi mi perfil me fui a inicio y fue todo.. Saludos

Comment: Si no lo has hecho aún, por favor lee la respuesta de fedorqui

Answer (score 5):

No es una información pública. De [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67402/209901):

> - Simply loading the site is not enough to count as a "visit".
>
>   - The exact amount of activity required to count as a visit is not public information

Es decir: cargar la página no es suficiente para que una visita cuente de cara a ganar las medallas de visitas en días consecutivos o que aparezca en el calendario del perfil.

Hay muchas hipótesis al respecto. La más extendida es que al menos hace falta ir a la página de inicio.

Comment: considera que el timezone de StackOverflow es en UTC, a mi me ha pasado en repetidas ocasiones, por eso inicio sesión todas las mañanas y todas las noches :D

Comment: @fredyfx ¡cierto! No es un problema para los que estamos cerca de Greenwich, pero los del otro lado del charco a buen seguro lo notáis :D

Comment: desconozco dónde queda Greenwich pero en la refri de la empresa he visto un sandwich que me anda haciendo ojitos xD!! hahaha :D

Comment: @fredyfx jajaja Greenwich es el meridiano 0, el que pasa por Londres e íntimamente ligado con UTC :)

Comment: hahaha gracias por la referencia geográfica :D creo que iré a visitar al sandwich al rato hahaha

Comment: @fredyfx creo que lo tienes _meridianamente_ claro, ¡ve antes que el UTC te lo coma!